# Generic argument with a number property

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create a function like this:

```
insert<T>(target: T, property: keyof T, value: number) {
    target[property] = value;
}
```

This code does not works. Because `target[property]` if of type `T[keyof T]` and typescript won't allow a number in this type.

I tried something like this :

```
insert<T extends {[p in P]: number}, P keyof T>(target: T, property: P, value: number)
```

But it does not work.

How can i make this function works ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix is to use value type directly from the mapped type:

```
function insert<T, K extends keyof T>
(target: T, property: K, value: T[K]) {
    target[property] = value;
}
```

The main change is:

- second generic `K`
- third argument type as `T[K]`

As your type has one value type, we can even have another solution without second generic:

```
function insert<T extends Record<string, number>>
(target: T, property: keyof T, value: T[keyof T]) {
    target[property] = value;
}
```

In this context when all keys represent the same value, `T[keyof T]` is also correct.

Comment: @Magus take a look that I have updated answer, in first solution you dont need to narrow `T` type at all. In second we need to do so as we are using `T[keyof T]`, pick what fits your need.